# React Native, element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, react-native

The same issue was already solved in several posts, but non of them helped me (I'm new to React Native, so possibly there is a solution, but I can't find it)

My code uses route and screen. 
**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen.js';

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
});
```

**HomeScreen.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  onPressLearnMore() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Learn More" onPress={() => this.onPressLearnMore()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

What is wrong?

The project structure:

[image]

Comment: What is your file structure? is App.js in the same directory with the screens directory? Can you post the complete error please?

Comment: really dumb mistake. I just didn't imported it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define the file type in your import.

Change this `import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen.js';`

To this `import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';`

Hope it helps.

Edit: Just to gather all information in this answer, as suggested in the comments you should also export your `App.js`

Comment: Is there any more code in your App.js? For instance, how are you exporting it?

Comment: App.js is not exported anywhere

Answer (score 2):

you must `export default App` in `app.js`